# we get our s**t together

Tags: phrase-usage

The phrase "we get our sh*t together" appears to mean "we start to make progress (in the new year - 2021)". But with the word "s**t" there, it sounds a bit vulgar to me.  I am not sure that this feeling of mine is a correct understanding of the English phrase.

New Year greetings, I expect from this author, who is a world-renowned neuroscientist with his work *The End of Faith* and *The Moral Landscape: How Science Can Determine Human Values*, would be graceful yet insightful without a trace of vulgarity.

How to properly understand the phrase?

> Sam Harris tweeted
> @SamHarrisOrg
> ·
> 5h
> Happy New Year, my friends. Let's make 2021 the year **we get our shit together**. Partying face

Comment: Yes, it is vulgar way of saying ["get one's **act** together"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+one's+act+together) but I wouldn't get my hopes too high about the quality of material to be found on Twitter. Both expressions are informal.

Comment: Your expectations are going to be dashed.  Your world-renowned neuroscientist seems quite capable of a bit of vulgarity.

Comment: Everybody's allowed some time off from being formal, even world-renowned neuroscientists. In a set expression like this, the word shit is not particularly vulgar: it just means **stuff**.

Comment: Ismo says ['shit' is the most complicated word in English](https://youtu.be/igh9iO5BxBo)